# for loop not working in java

Tags: java, for-loop

I am trying to make  a binary converter in java. But I am getting an error in the for loop saying "Type mismatch: cannot convert from int to boolean". I have looked online and am doing exactly what it tells me to do.
here is my code.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class hsdgsd{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int[] count = {1,2,4,8,16,32,64,128};
        int[] binary;
        int[] binarynew;
        binary = new int[8];
        binarynew = new int[8];
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int num = in.nextInt();
        System.out.println(num);
        if (num <= 255){
            for (int i=8; i=0; i--)
            {
                if(num >= count[i]){

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `i=0` is not a boolean. Perhaps you meant i>=0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your for loop is doing what it should, but you coded it wrong.

```
for (int i=8; i=0; i--)
```

here you are saying: `i = 8` and: `perform while (set i to 0)`
which makes no sense.

change it to:

```
for (int i=8; i>0; i--)
```

EDIT: as T.J. points out, you have an array with 8 elements, meaning the biggest possible index is 7 (array.size - 1).

To work correctly, it should be:

```
for (int i = 7; i >= 0; i--)
```

Comment: `i>0` will miss out the 0th element. For that matter, starting with 8 will cause an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` on the first pass.

Comment: You're right. I based myself on the for loop in the question.

Answer (score 0):

`for (int i=8; i=0; i--)` is not correct, you are setting the value of i to zero again

replace it with

```
 for (int i=8; i>0; i--)
```